# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException after checking size

Tags: java, android, arrays

I have this error reported from an user in adapter. I can't reproduce this:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=8; index=8
```

at this line

```
if (columnas.get(column).getENTR() == 3)
```

but I don't understand, because I checked  `if (columnas.size() > column)` before. How can I fix this error? Sample code is below.

```
private List<bdcolums> columnas = new ArrayList<bdcolums>();

 private View getHeader(final int row, final int column, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null || convertView != inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_table_header, parent, false)) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_table_header, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.header_desc = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text2);
        holder.header_nom = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
        holder.header_img = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.dibuheader);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    if (columnas.size() > column) {
        if (columnas.get(column).getENTR() == 3) {
       //do something
        }
    } else {
        //do something
    }
    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: Please post the full stack trace.

Comment: It seems like everything is fine. Maybe exception occures in `getENTR()` method. Can you post more detailed stacktrace.

Comment: what kind of adapter are you using ?

Comment: Is this a multithreaded application? If ArrayList was modified in another thread by removing an item, exactly after the check and before the access , then you will get this exception.

Comment: please post your `getENTR()` method

Comment: You had initialize the list but where you had added the items to it.

Answer (score 0):

This is because your array(column) has been accessed with illegal address. Try using arrayList instead of array . and see these questions for further assistance.

[What causes a java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException and how do I prevent it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554734/what-causes-a-java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-and-how-do-i-prevent-it)
[java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=4; index=4 length array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22806781/java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-length-4-index-4-length-array)
[Login Web Service Exception(716): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13525025/login-web-service-exception716-java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-leng)

Hope it helps ... :)